# Finding the moment of inertia for a sphere.

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find the moment of inertia for a sphere of radius 1, with density of $1-r^2$ at a point distance $r$ from the center.  I already found the mass which is $\frac{8\pi}{15}$, but now I'm trying to find the moment of inertia if rotated around the z axis.  Any help is appreciated, although it'd be awesome if someone could take me step by step through the problem.

Comment: Can you add working showing how you got the mass. This will better let others understand your working and level of understanding of the concepts involved.

Comment: @IanMiller: OP appears to have gotten the mass by [asking and receiving](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548329).

Comment: Ah, Thanks @AndrewD.Hwang. I should have checked his other questions.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the moment of inertia your working will be similar to the mass. What makes it harder is for the mass you used spherical coordinates (as the density only depends on the radius) where as the moment of inertia needs to be calculated in cylindrical coordinates.

You need to break the sphere into infinitely thin parts and add/integrate those together. There are two choices: You can divide it up into thin disks perpendicular to the axis of rotation or you can divide it up into thin cylindrical shells parallel to the axis of rotation. These two approaches just reflect if we intregrate over $r$ or $z$ first.

**Density**

Currently the density is given spherically as $\rho=1-r^2$. This needs to be changed to cylindrical coordinates. It becomes:

$$\rho=1-r^2-z(r)^2$$

**Moment of Inertia**

$$I=\int_V r^2 dm$$

$$I=\int_V r^2 \rho(r) dV$$

**Thin Cylindrical Shells**

Each cylindrical shell will have a radius $r$ and will have a thickness of $dr$ so a cross-sectional area of $2\pi rdr$ and will be made up of multiple rings each having a height of $dz$ where $z$ depends upon $r$ by $z^2+r^2=1$. So:

$$\int_0^1 2\int_0^\sqrt{1-r^2}r^2(1-r^2-z^2)\times2\pi r\,dz\,dr$$

**Thin Circular Disks**

Each thin circular disk will have a thickness of dz. They will be made of multiple thin rings of radius of $r$ and thickness $dr$ and so each ring has cross-sectional area of $2\pi r dr$. So:

$$2\int_0^1 \int_0^\sqrt{1-z^2} r^2(1-r^2-z^2)\times2\pi r\,dr\,dz$$

**Answer**
Performing either integral will give you: $$\frac{8\pi}{105}$$